# Best type of chart or plot to visualize geographic distribution of servers

Tags: data-visualization

I am doing some research on a provider's network geographical distribution. If my data looks like this:

| Country | Quantity | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ireland | 5 | Europe |
| Singapore | 9 | Asia |
| Canada | 25 | North America |
| UK | 43 | Europe |
| USA | 50 | North America |

but for 70 countries and 2,000 servers. How could I best visually display this? The relationship I'm trying to show is the potential even or uneven geographic distribution of servers while also taking in to consideration the fact that the USA would have more servers than a country than the size of Ireland or Hungary. This seems like the least complicated way of controlling for size rather than getting into population, etc.

Would a Lorenz curve or Gina coefficient be meaningful in this instance?

Comment: A visualization of a geographic distribution is called a *map.*  The [gis.se] site is devoted to making maps and analyzing geographic data: check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest visualisation here is just a map. You could:

1. overlay circles (or any other shape) on the countries and make the <strike>size</strike> area proportional to the quantity of interest. Or use circles of the same size for every country and use colour to indicate variation in number.
2. colour the countries by the quantity of interest.

EDIT: As whuber notes below, chloropleth maps (option #2) have weaknesses. I think this is true of most mapping options, but it's worth considering alternatives. This thread has a few: [Data Visualization: Alternatives to Choropleth maps for spatial data and statistical graphics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/136007/121522)

Comment: "Color the countries," *aka* a *choropleth map,* is not great advice, because the visual impression it creates is proportional to the mapped area of each country.  That can introduce pronounced distortions and misleading maps.  The first (use symbol size) is better, but much depends on the details. For instance, making the shape *diameters* proportional to the quantity will cause the visual impression of each circle to vary with the *square* of the quantity, again introducing a huge Lie Factor.

Comment: +1 for the link.  Concerning how to scale symbol size: although I prefer using the area, I feel obliged to point out that cartographers have studied and attempted to quantify the "visual impact" of a scaled point symbol.  Some have concluded that the diameter (which in area scaling is proportional to the $0.5$ power of the quantity) ought to be scaled in proportion to the $0.59$ power: something of a compromise between area scaling and size scaling.  YMMV, but it's worth knowing.  See [Dent's *Cartography*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borden_Dent) for an account of this.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use proportional colored circles (or squares), showing simultaneously absolute numbers and ratios.

If you want to show the absolute number of servers, while taking into account the "size of the country" (e.g. the number of inhabitants, the total number of computers in this country, or whatever you think is relevant), then you can create a new variable using this information as a denominator for your quantity.
For example, let's take the quantity per one million residents:

| Country | Quantity | Continent | Quantity per 1M residents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ireland | 5 | Europe | 0.7 |
| Singapore | 9 | Asia | 1.7 |
| Canada | 25 | North America | 0.6 |
| UK | 43 | Europe | 0.6 |
| USA | 50 | North America | 0.1 |

Then, you'll use the variables "quantity" and "quantity per 1M people" in your map, with the two following features:

- circles representing the absolute value of your variable "quantity"
- a shade of a color of your choice, representing the ratio. A lighter shade will mean a value close to zero, and a darker shade a value far from zero.

Below is an example of this kind of map. Note that in this specific case, it uses two colors (blue and red), to distinguish between positive and negative ratios, but in your case you'll probably need just one color (as hopefully you don't have a negative quantity of servers):
[image: Map of Europe, showing compound annual growth rate against total population]
([source](https://magrit.cnrs.fr/docs/carto/propsmbolchoro_fr.html))

Here, the "compound annual growth rate" would be our "servers per 1 million people" variable, and the "total population" would be our quantity of servers.

If you're concerned about overlapping circles, they generally do not hinder the understanding of the message you want to convey. Otherwise, you generally can tweak a bit your mapping software to find a solution, like defining a smaller maximum size of the circles.

Comment: Contouring the *numbers* of servers is so strange as to be almost uninterpretable.  For criticism of your last (filled area map) see my comment to another answer in this thread.

Comment: @whuber Indeed. Maybe I've been a bit too enthusiatic :) I edited the answer and just kept the proportional circles + color suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make a xy scatter plot, with number of servers on the y-axis and some useful comparison property on the x-axis (population size, internet users, GDP, etc).

Hans Rosling's graphs may provide inspiration:
https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=Hans+Rosling+graphs&atb=v101-1&iax=images&ia=images

Another possibility is to go with a map, but distort it by something, for example population size:
https://medium.com/google-news-lab/tilegrams-make-your-own-cartogram-hexmaps-with-our-new-tool-df46894eeec1
You could distort make a scaled with the number of servers, and compare to one scaled with the population size.